# Minifiedjs, npm and Browserify

Tags: javascript, npm, gulp, browserify, minifiedjs

http://minifiedjs.com

Minified Website states:

No matter whether you are including Minified with a script tag or you use a synchronous loader like RequireJS, it is recommended to use the following lines to define the five essential references:

var MINI = require('minified');
var *=MINI.*, $=MINI.$, $$=MINI.$$, EE=MINI.EE, HTML=MINI.HTML;

I have used this but it just fails to assign a minified object to MINI.

$(function(){

});

This fails with a 
app.js:36TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'MINI._')

This is not a standard use of embedded link to the code but using Browserify and Gulp in WebStorm and after installing using npm.

JQuery, ScrollMagic, GSAP or any other package seems to work fine but even though the Minified Module code exists in the build the MINI.$ ref is undefined...

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Are you using a AMD loader, or just Minified? Have you tried removing other components to find out where the conflict is?

Comment: Yes I have tried it vanilla and I can just embed the code using src="pat-to-minified-web-src.js" and it works... Its when I use require('minified') in my code and also then Browserfiy using a gulp task.